# How to UNNEST a column with nested array values in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a listed of voucher description in a **column** named '**data**' and want to unnest it to get the voucher code in my query output:

```
"bd_voucher_data":{"voucher_id":1432132,"voucher_code":"THANKYOU2B"}}
```

I tried the following but it does not not work:

```
     select date,
        shopid, voucher_id, voucher_code,
        from voucher_table
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data.bd_voucher_data) t (voucher_id,voucher_code)
        where date > date('2020-01-01')
```

Does anyone know why it does not work?

Comment: Do you get no result or returns with an error, if so what error is shown ..?

Comment: For one, there is a typo (an additional ',') after the 'voucher_code' column used in your `select` statement